# How to ignore HTTP errors in a iMacros script?

Tags: url, imacros

I have 1000+ URLs that I want to scrape to retrieve the title value from the HTML. After trying different things, I ultimately used iMacros scripts, which I don't know anything about. Nonetheless, I managed to make a script after reading guides.

My script is working perfectly but has a problem: When leeching URLs titles, if it encounters an HTTP error (e.g. dead link, forbidden page, etc), it crashes with an error message like this one:

> Error -1350: Error loading page. Http status 403. Line 4: URL GOTO=http://url.com

Instead of crashing when the script encounters these errors, I would like it to simply skip the URL and continue running. How can I modify my script to do this? Here is my script:

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://google.com/
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TITLE ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=d:/ FILE=links.txt
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
```

Output:

```
http://google.com/,Google
```

I would also like to replace the comma after the URL in the output with a semicolon.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use [!ERRORIGNORE](http://wiki.imacros.net/!ERRORIGNORE)

Comment: can u pls tell me how to use that?

maybe reedit my config with your modifications

and do we need to add this line for every url, cause ill copy paste these lines multiple times

Comment: Just place the line `SET !ERRORIGNORE YES` above all of your other commands

Comment: ok, and how to remove this error it comes with even with correct urls    http://i.imgur.com/8UP9uMD.jpg

Comment: If its the error in the original post than that line should fix that error.

Comment: thanks brennan for such great helping    one last thing

.
how to replace , from result to a tab or space 
http://google.com/,Google

Comment: Im not quite sure of that, try searching stack overflow for your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86816/discussion-between-texh-and-brennan-mcdonald).

Answer (score 1):

At critical points where you don't want to exit at fails:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
```

If you want to revert back at some point to do stop on an error:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
```

You can use these two as many times as you like, even every second row turn on and off.